# Django model.py models.ForeignKey()

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie on Django framework and a bit confused on the models.

When a "class" in the model.py, can I just understand it as "table" in database? For example, in the code below, "Test", "Contact", and "Tag" are all tables in the database used by Django?

```
from django.db import models

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Contact(models.Model):  
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=200)        
    age    = models.IntegerField(default=0)        
    email  = models.EmailField()       
    def __unicode__(self):            
       return self.name

class Tag(models.Model):        
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In the class `Tag`, it is using `models.ForeignKey(Contact)`, based on my understanding, the foreignkey should be established on one specific column of a table, but why the `ForeignKey` is establish on a table directly, i.e. Table `Contact`?

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can understand your classes as a table in the database ONLY IF it extends `models.Model` class.

This becomes a table:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    pass
```

This will not become a model:

```
class SomeHelper():
    ....
```

As for the ForeignKey, it will automatically be tied to the primary key of the other model. You can change that by setting `to_field` in that ForeignKey but the default is `pk`:

```
models.ForeignKey(Bar, to_field='non-pk-field')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it does help me!

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key is establishing to the column which has **primary key**.
only one primary key will be in a table,
 **So in django you only have to give the table name. It will automatically establish with the column which having primary key**.
 If you are not mentioning any primary key in your column django models will automatically add one `id` column which will have unique not null integer value for each entry.
If you want to explicitly give foreign key to a specific column you can do like this :

```
models.ForeignKey(TableName, db_column='Column_name')
```

Comment: @HenryJ glad to help you .

Comment: @HenryJ oh its sounds great, welcome to stack overflow, feel free to share your doubts and try to give answer for others too. Thanks